# output sql with html structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, database-view

Is there a way to store the HTML structure in a SQL view and output it with the stored HTML structure via controller?

For e.g. Here is a sample HTML which I'd like to store in a SQL View and output via controller

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<vwStudent>>" %>

<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Student ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                GPA
            </th>
            <th>
                Scholarship Amount
            </th>
            <th>
                Eligible Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Is Senior
            </th>
        </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.StudentID) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.FName) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.GPA) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:F}", item.ScholarshipAmount)) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", item.EligibleDate)) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Convert.ToString(item.IsSenior) == "True" ? "Yes" : Convert.ToString(item.IsSenior) == "False" ? "No" : null%>
            </td>   
        </tr>

    <% } %>

    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Students()
{
    ViewData.Model = students.vwStudent.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to store the HTML in a sql table? You should keep data and html seperate in your application - that is literally the whole point is using MVC!

Comment: You store the data (ie. the fields like StudentId) in the database, and then your view (the cshtml file from asp.net mvc) renders it into HTML format.

Comment: @Milney I am trying to address a performance issue, Database query executes in under 10 seconds whereas the html view takes over 5 minutes to output. I am trying to make the view output faster

Comment: How many records are we talking? Pulling the HTML from the database WILL NOT speed up rendering... think about it - it will still have to render it after pulling from the database... You must have another issue. Post your Controller Action code, I bet it is something in there!

Comment: @Milney over 65k records

Comment: @Milney added controller action. controller action is just populating the ViewData.Model with the data which is then displayed in the view

Comment: 65k records?? it is a bad idea to render all at one time. Can't you just fetch top 20 or 50 and on pagination get follow-up records? and as @Milney pointed out.. storing this in Database will not help at all

Comment: 65K records usually requires pagination which fetches data depending on how many results a user want to view. Note that HTML tags structure should be separated from any business logic, including database content.

Comment: + Pagination is the solution for this. Look at IPagedList, this handles it for you easily: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/

Answer (score 1):

65,000 records is FAR FAR too many to render on a single page... you should use pagination. There are libraries to help with this like this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/